# Sync between database tables and SharePoint online lists using ODBC. best approach to do so

Tags: sharepoint, odbc, power-automate, csom

We have 5 tables inside a database and we want to sync the data inside those tables to SharePoint online lists. All the modifications will still happen on the database tables, so the sync should only sync New/edited/Deleted data from the database to SharePoint and not from the other side.
The database tables can be accessed using ODBC. So what are the approaches we have to do such a sync:-

- Using Power Automate Flow which runs on schedule basis?
- Write a .net console application which reads the data from the database and update SharePoint using CSOM?
- Other approaches

Any advice?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I've been working on a PowerAutomate sync between an Excel Table and a bundle of Sharepoint lists, and one component that is proving quite useful for the Excel -> Sharepoint update direction is the "Sharepoint File or Folder Created or Modified" trigger.

If your database platform has the capacity to create small csv or json files corresponding to the changes you want to make, then one option might be to set aside some "new, change, delete" folders accessible to your PowerAutomate profile and to have your system pass in files with the records to be changed.  Particularly if your db tables are particularly large, this might be a more efficient solution than periodically scouring the whole table to try to identify those changes proactively.

Answer (score 0):

This SharePoint batch templates page now has a template to do a full sync of a SharePoint list from other databases using Power Automate: https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Power-Automate-Cookbook/Batch-Update-Create-and-Upsert-SharePoint-Lists/td-p/1365410